# new android project share/copy the same string.xml file

Tags: android, eclipse

I am new to the android development as well as eclipse IDE, but I do have some experience in using Java (Used to work with C# in vs2008 before). Right now I have both Eclipse and Android SDK up and running. I did manage to do the "Hello, world" in android. But when ever I am making a new project it shows up in the solution explorer next to the previous project "Hello, World" and it shares/copy the string.xml, so when ever I run it, it give me Hello World previous project result.

Please tell me what to do and thank you.

Comment: What version of Eclipse do you use? What steps do you take in order to create a new project?

Comment: I am having Eclipse Helios build 20100617-1415

To Make a new project I do, File-New-Android Project, I fill the information and finish.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure it is sharing the file? Whenever you create a new Android project in Eclipse, it will make a default `strings.xml` for you, containing:

```
<resources>
<string name="hello">Hello World, [...]!</string>
<string name="app_name">[...]</string>
</resources>
```

And your new projects will simply appear below your old ones in the Eclipse Navigator/Package Explorer (if you are using the same workspace). You can switch workspace or remove the old `HelloWorld` project if you don't want it to be there.

If you try to 'run' a particular file in a project it will only run the associated project, so there is no harm in having multiple projects in a workspace.